# How to use "torch.scatter_" in 3D or 4D tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to write the values from my source tensor into another tensor at the indices specified in the index tensor using [torch scatter](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html).

This works well for 2D tensors:

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [-11.,  -6., -10.]])
print(f'my_tensor dim {my_tensor.shape}')        
my_indices = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1]])
placeholder = torch.zeros(2,5)
out = placeholder.scatter_(1, my_indices, my_tensor) # reorder tensor by indices into placeholder
out
>>> my_tensor dim torch.Size([2, 3])
tensor([[  1.,   0.,   0.,   2.,   3.],
        [  0., -10., -11.,   0.,  -6.]])
```

But how can I do this for 3D tensors?

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]]])
print(f'my_tensor dim {my_tensor.shape}')
my_indices = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1]])
placeholder = torch.zeros(2,5)
out = placeholder.scatter_(1, my_indices, my_tensor) # reorder tensor by indices
out
>>> my_tensor dim torch.Size([4, 2, 3])
RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as src tensor
```

Or 4D tensors?

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([[[[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]]], [[[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]], [[  1.,   2.,   3.],[-11.,  -6., -10.]]]])
print(f'my_tensor dim {my_tensor.shape}')
my_indices = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1]])
placeholder = torch.zeros(2,5)
out = placeholder.scatter_(1, my_indices, my_tensor) # reorder tensor by indices
out
>>> my_tensor dim torch.Size([2, 4, 2, 3])
RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as src tensor
```

I tried adding a dimension to the indices tensor as it says:

```
my_indices = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1]]).unsqueeze(0)
```

But I'm getting the same error